# Java programming style

Tags: java

its a maybe a dumb question but i am curious to understand this thing....
The below code works but the one below that doesn't work.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Menu extends JFrame
{

public Menu()
{

JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("exit.png");
JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
JMenuItem fileClose = new JMenuItem("Close",icon);
fileClose.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
fileClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{System.exit(0);}
});


file.add(fileClose);
menubar.add(file);
setJMenuBar(menubar);


setVisible(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(300,200);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}


public static void main (String args[])
{
new Menu();
}


}
```

The below one doesn't work

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Menu extends JFrame
{

public Menu()
{


setVisible(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(300,200);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);

JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("exit.png");
JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
JMenuItem fileClose = new JMenuItem("Close",icon);
fileClose.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
fileClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{System.exit(0);}
});


file.add(fileClose);
menubar.add(file);
setJMenuBar(menubar);


}


public static void main (String args[])
{
new Menu();
}


}
```

I thought Java supports free style coding !!! (that's what it says in my Book)

*PS: Please Someone Edit the Tile to suit the question correctly, I am not sure what to put in Title.*

Comment: You do see that actual code differs in those examples, right? I mean, beyond style.

Comment: in the 1st set methods are defined after JmenuBar . while in the 2nd it is written up. I always used to declare at the top for my other codes untill now.  PS. I started learning swings this morning about 3 hours before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your 2nd code sample is that you are calling `setVisible` before you actually add stuff to the GUI. Your saying "*Here's some stuff, now show*" while in the second one your saying "*Show, now here's some stuff*"

**Fix:** Move setVisible to the end of the constructor

Comment: So is it a good practice to always call setVisible at the end . Or should i define it in the main class . Also wat about other set methods like setSize, setLocationRelativeTo, where should i call them ???

Comment: You can call `setVisible` anywhere, as long as its **after** you've setup the GUI. For clearness I always put it at the end of the constructor. The other methods you mentioned are fine anywhere before `setVisible`, since they are only used when drawing